# integral equation and laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

Solve the following integral equation

$ u(x)= \cos x - \int_{0}^{x} (x-y)cos(x-y)u(y) dy $

I applied Laplace transforms to the above integral equation and so the initial equation is written as:

$ U(s)= \frac{s}{s^2+1} - \frac{(s^2 -1)U(s)}{(s^2+1)^2} $

and  then I concluded to this : $U(s)= \frac{s^2+1}{s(s^2+3)} $ .

At this point I've been stuck. I can't find the  function  $u(x)$ whose laplace transform is the above... I would appreciate any help!!!!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: **Hint:** $(s^2+1)/(s (s^2+3)) = 2 s/(3 (s^2+3))+1/(3 s)$

Comment: So is $ u(x)= \frac {2 cos \sqrt 3 x +1}{3} $ ? Have I done this right? Thank you for your time

Comment: Looks great...!

Comment: You're right!! Thanks a lot again!!! :)

Comment: Note - I am assuming you calculated $U(s)$ correctly as I did not check that part.

Comment: I verified the answer and it's correct!